# PHP - SQL - Query not working

Tags: php, sql

I am very new to PHP and I was wondering if I could get some feedback on the code below, I don't see why its not working.

```
$i = 0;
$companyService = $_POST['companyService']; // Array variable


for ($i; $i<count($companyService); $i++) {

    $service = $companyService[$i];
    echo $service; // works and provides correct value
    echo $companyId; // works and provides correct value
    $queryService = "INSERT INTO `companySpTable` (`companyId`,`serviceId`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$companyId)."' ,'".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$service)."'";

    if(!mysqli_query($link,$queryService)) {

         $error = "<p> Query not executed</p>".$error;


    }
```

Comment: (1) `not working` is entirely too vague for anyone to know what is going on.  (2) You should use parameters, not munge query strings with such input.

Comment: (3) Add a `)` in your query.

Comment: `$error` is never defined so that won't help. Use the error function, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php. Also the `for` can define the `$i`, and I'd use a `foreach`.